# react material along with react infinite scroll component table body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to use react infinite scroll inside react material table.
I tried using it but i could only wrap the whole table and the scrolling effects the whole page and i want the headers to stay sticky and only the table body to infinite scroll
any solution? thanks

Comment: It it works for you, you can achieve this with html/css easily. Check out `https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-a-table-with-a-fixed-header-and-scrollable-body.html`

Answer (score 0):

```
<TableContainer>
     <Table sx={{
          height: '80vh' // set a height
       }}>
        <TableHeader stickyHeader> // to stick header to the top of table container
             // header 
         </TableHeader>
        <TableBody>
            //body
        </TableBody>
     </Table>
</TableContainer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. it doesn't solve my problem, i want the table body to be infinite scroll

Comment: Im currently using the same in my project and it works the same as your expectation